# Make facebook posts with ionic/angular app

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app with the ionic framework and integrate the [facebookConnectPlugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) for login and making posts to a fan page.

The login part is working properly, I can see the user data and display on the app. The problem I'm having is when I try to make a post to facebook.

This is the complete controller that manage the login and the post

```
.controller('signupCtrl', function($scope, $state, $q, UserService, $ionicLoading){
// This is the success callback from the login method
var accesstoken;
var fbLoginSuccess = function(response){
    if (!response.authResponse){
        fbLoginError("Cannot find the authResponse");
        return;
    }

    var authResponse = response.authResponse;
    accesstoken = authResponse.accessToken;

    getFacebookProfileInfo(authResponse).then(function(profileInfo){
        // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on local storage
        UserService.setUser({
            authResponse: authResponse,
            userID: profileInfo.id,
            name: profileInfo.name,
            email: profileInfo.email,
            picture: "http://graph.facebook.com/" + authResponse.userID + "/picture?type=large"
        });
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(fail){
            // Fail get profile info
            alert('profile info fail ' + fail);
        });
};

// This is the fail callback from the login method
var fbLoginError = function(error){
    alert('fbLoginError ' + error);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
};
    // This method is to get the user profile info from the facebook api
var getFacebookProfileInfo = function (authResponse){
    var info = $q.defer();

    facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=email,name&access_token=' + authResponse.accessToken, null,
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            info.resolve(response);
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            info.reject(response);
        }
    );
    return info.promise;
};

//This method is executed when the user press the "Login with facebook" button
$scope.facebookSignIn = function(){
    console.log('---> facebookSignIn');
    facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(success){
        if (success.status === 'connected'){
            // The user is logged in and has authenticated your app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed request, and the time the access token
            // and signed request each expire
            //alert('getLoginStatus ' + success.status);

            // Check if we have our user saved
            var user = UserService.getUser('facebook');

            if (!user.userID){
                alert('UNO');
                getFacebookProfileInfo(success.authResponse).then(function(profileInfo) {
                    // For the purpose of this example I will store user data on local storage
                    UserService.setUser({
                        authResponse: success.authResponse,
                        userID: profileInfo.id,
                        name: profileInfo.name,
                        email: profileInfo.email,
                        picture: "http://graph.facebook.com/" + success.authResponse.userID + "/picture?type=large"
                    });

                    //$state.go('menu.home');
                }, function(fail){
                        // Fail get profile info
                        alert('profile info fail ' + fail);
                   });
            }else{
                //alert('DOS');
                $state.go('menu.home');
                var fan_token = 'EAAH1eElPgZBl1jwZCI0BADZBlrZCbsZBWF5ig29V1Sn5ABsxH1o4kboMhpjZBDfKtD1lfDK1dJLcZBI4gRBOF2XGjOmWMXD0I8jtPZA4xLJNZADarOGx8fiXBRZCTOaxwBLQEwRjsvaqTtb2DTCI0Qdo3haX6vqHlJoWMZD';

                console.log('access token', accesstoken);

                facebookConnectPlugin.api(
                    '/186259017448757/feed', 
                    'POST', 
                    {
                        access_token: fan_token, 
                        'message':'HOLA!'
                    }, 
                    function(response){console.log(response);alert(response.id)}
                )
            }
        }else{
            // If (success.status === 'not_authorized') the user is logged in to Facebook,
            // but has not authenticated your app
            // Else the person is not logged into Facebook,
            // so we're not sure if they are logged into this app or not.

            alert('getLoginStatus ' + success.status);

            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: 'Logging in...'
            });

            // Ask the permissions you need. You can learn more about
            // FB permissions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4
            facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email', 'public_profile'], fbLoginSuccess, fbLoginError);
        }
    });
};
})
```

This is the part where I try to make a post to a facebook wall

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api('/181297057448657/feed', 'POST', {access_token: fan_token, 'message':'HOLA!'}, 
                    function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        alert(response.id)
                    }
                )
```

I went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to generate the access tokens, tried with several tokens (user, fanpage, etc) but any seem to work. I've also used this code snippet provided in the facebook devs explorer tool

```
FB.api(
  '/174801556748297/feed',
  'POST',
  {"message":"testing3"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

The result is always the same, I get a JSON error in the response object and no facebook post to the wall

Any help would be really appreciated!

*PD: app ID's have been modified, that why they don't match. Same with the tokens and fan page ID*

Comment: What is the error message returned?

Comment: JSON error, just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  following in my app to post ,Reference https://github.com/ccoenraets/sociogram-angular-ionic

```
 $scope.share = function () {
        OpenFB.post('/me/feed', $scope.item)
            .success(function () {
              console.log("done");
              $ionicLoading.hide();
              $scope.item.message="";
              $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Post successfully on Facebook!', noBackdrop: true, duration: 2000 });
                $scope.status = "This item has been shared from OpenFB";
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                alert(data.error.message);
            });
    };
```

*HTML*

```
 <div class="media-body"> 
      <textarea  placeholder="What's on your mind?" ng-model="item.message"></textarea> 
    </div>
    <hr style="margin-top: -1px;" />
    <div style="text-align:right;padding-right:20px;padding-bottom:10px;">
      <button class="fb-login" ng-click="share()">Post to Facebook</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! will look into it

Comment: It is working for me .If works for you too then approve answer and close issue . Thanks